# how to save the testng-results.xml file to different folder other than test-output folder?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng

I need help on saving the testng-results.xml (that gets created automatically) into my folder [Folder name(with current date): outputfolder_11-11-2013]

This is how I am running my testng.xml:

```
1. I use eclipse
2. right click on testng.xml > Run as > TestNg Suite
3. I added a "-usedefaultlisteners false" in the Arguments box of the 
   "Run Configurations"
```

When I run my testng.xml with the above settings, it is not creating testng-results.xml.

I want either of below two things to be done from my Configurations in Eclipse:
**1. I want testng-results.xml to be created and saved in my(given) folder "outputfolder_11-11-2013_13-10-02", This is dynamically created folder with the current system time (outputfolder_DD-MM-YYYY_HH-MM-SS)**

OR

**2. I want to save testng-results.xml by appending current date and time in my local folder "TESTOUTPUT". I should be abel to identify results file with the time stamp. My test-results.xml should be this way "testng-results_11-11-2013_13-56-34.xml (testng-results_DD-MM-YYYY_HH-MM-SS.xml)**

How shall I achieve this by configuring eclipse? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reconfigure XML Reporter: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging-xml-reports

Comment: I am not using command line. I am running testng.xml by Right click > Run as Testng Suite. please let em know how can I configure it in testng.xml ?

Comment: Menu: Run > Run Configurations > select your test > arguments tab. In general case all runs(Tests, apps, debug, servers, etc) in Eclipse could be configured similar to command line run.

Comment: But I want testng-results.xml to be created and saved in my(given) folder "outputfolder_11-11-2013". this folder is getting created dynamically by taking the current system time (outputfolder_MM_DD_YYYY). How can I handle this in eclipse configuration? (but not from command line)

Comment: In eclipse run configuration you could add parameters -d test_result_${env_var:%DATE%}_${env_var:%TIME%} that tell testng where is output folder. ${env_var} is eclipse flag that read env variables. BUT.... this contains lot of bugs.